# How do I specify a format string to flake8?

Tags: python, flake8

**Update:**
Using a string for --format DOES appear to work, even though you get the WARNING message below. I reran with different format than the default and I got the WARNING message, but my output matched the string. Bug?

**Original:**
The docs for flake8's [--format](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/options.html#cmdoption-flake8-format) option seem to indicate that in addition to a named formatter, I can also use a format string. However, I've tried it using the string in the docs as a test and it doesn't work:

```
flake8.main.application   MainProcess    112 WARNING  "%(path)s::%(row)d,%(col)d::%(code)s::%(text)s" is an unknown formatter. Falling back to default.
```

I am using `python3.9 -m flake8 -config=/path/to/a/configfile` where the config file has the lines:

```
[flake8]
format = %(path)s::%(row)d,%(col)d::%(code)s::%(text)s
```

Help?

Answer (score 1):

it does work, but currently produces a warning (which are hidden by default -- you must have some setting enabling the verbose logging)

I plan to split these options at some point, but it's difficult to do without breaking existing usecases

disclaimer: I'm the current flake8 maintainer

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. Good luck with that backwards compatibility. It’s always a problem (see the current trials and tribulations over Perl 7. LOL)